# I am getting 'in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array' when no boxes are checked

Tags: php

I get this error message:

`Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /home/bushvmcs/public_html/bookings.php on line 221`

I am trying to make my checkboxes "sticky". If no boxes are checked it should only give me a warning to remind me to choose the courses, or tell me to check the right amount of boxes.
On top I have this coding:

```
  <?php
  $errors = array();
  $missing = array();
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $to = "Carel Venter <bookings@bushveldgolf.co.za>";
  $subject = "Booking";
  $expected = array ('b_name', 'b_surn', 'b_tele', 'b_mail', 'b_acco', 'b_golf', 'b_nong', 'b_pack', 'b_courses', 'b_dfrom', 'b_dto');
  $required = array ('b_name', 'b_surn', 'b_tele', 'b_mail', 'b_acco', 'b_golf', 'b_nong', 'b_pack', 'b_courses', 'b_dfrom', 'b_dto');
    if (!isset($_POST['b_courses'])) {
    $_POST['b_courses'] = array();
   }
   $minimumChecked = 1;
   if (count($_POST['b_courses']) < $minimumChecked) {
    $errors['b_courses'] = true;
   }
```

And then my checkboxes code:

```
 <td>Courses:</td>
        <td><label><?php  if (isset($errors['b_courses'])) { ?>
        <span class="warning">Please select the right amount of courses 
          <?php  echo   $minimumChecked; ?></span>
      <?php } ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="b_courses[]" value="elements" id="b-courses_0" 
        <?php 
        if ($_POST && in_array('elements', $b_courses)) {
            echo 'checked';
            }   
        ?>/>
            Elements Private Golf Reserve<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="b_courses[]" value="zebula" id="b_courses_1" 
            <?php 
        if ($_POST && in_array('zebula', $b_courses)) {
            echo 'checked';
            }   
        ?>/>
            Zebula Golf Estate and Spa<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="b_courses[]" value="euphoria" id="b_courses_2" 
            <?php 
        if ($_POST && in_array('euphoria', $b_courses)) {
            echo 'checked';
            }   
        ?>/>
            Euphoria Golf Estate<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="b_courses[]" value="koro" id="b_courses_3" 
            <?php 
             if ($_POST && in_array('koro', $b_courses)) {
            echo 'checked';
            }   
           ?>/>
             Koro Creek Bushveld Golf Estate<br />
          </label></td>
```

Here is my mail process file:

```
   <?php
$suspect = false;
$pattern = '/Content-Type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';
function isSuspect($val, $pattern, &$suspect) {
if  (is_array($val)) {
foreach ($val as $item) {
isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
}
} else {
if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
$suspect = true;
}
}
  }
    isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);
if (is_array($val)) {
foreach ($val as $item) {
isSuspect($item, $pattern, $suspect);
}
} else {
if (preg_match($pattern, $val)) {
$suspect = true;
}
}   
 isSuspect($_POST, $pattern, $suspect);
    if (!$suspect) {
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
    $missing[] = $key;
    $$key = ''; 
} elseif (in_array($key, $expected)) {
    $$key = $temp;
}
}
  }
  if (!$suspect && !empty($b_mail)) {
$validemail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'b_mail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($validemail) {
$headers .= "\r\nReply-to: $validemail";
} else  {
    $errors['b_mail'] = true;
}
  }
  if (!$suspect && !$missing && !$errors) {
$message = '';
foreach ($expected as $item) {
    if (isset($$item) && !empty($$item)) {
        $val = $$item;
    } else {
        $val = 'Not selected';
    }
if (is_array($val)) {
    $val = implode(', ', $val);
}
$item = str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $item);
$message .= ucfirst($item) . ": $val\r\n\r\n";
}
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
$mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if (!$mailsent) {
    $errors['mailfail'] = true;
}
  }
?>
```

Comment: Where did you set the variable `$b_courses`? We can see that `$_POST['b_courses']` is an array, but not `$b_courses` itself.

Comment: This is line 221 if ($_POST && in_array('elements', $b_courses)) { It also gives the error on the other three similar line as well. I set the variable on the "php include" file. Here is:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 `you need to check whether array is empty before using in_array()
```

if ($_POST && !empty($b_courses) && in_array('elements', $b_courses)) {
            echo 'checked';
            }`

Comment: I removed the if ($_POST && in_array('zebula', $b_courses)) {
            echo 'checked';
            } and replaced it with this code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
if( !is_array( $_POST['b_courses'] ) )
{
    $_POST['b_courses'] = array( $_POST['b_courses'] );
}
```

After your `!isset( $_POST['b_courses'] )` test.